# Debugging a Web API Project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-api-testing

I currently have a solution which contains two projects: an ASP.NET site and a Web API project.  On the site, I have a page that is meant to call the API using the POST method at address http://localhost:52855/api/v1/GetPrices asynchronously (e.g. response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken where "base" is a DelegatingHandler).  Part of the data that is posted is an API key along with a signature to ensure the user is authorized.  However, nothing happens; the Chrome tab just shows the loading symbol continuously.

But, if I use Fiddler and make a POST request to the same address (http://localhost:52855/api/v1/GetPrices), but without the API/signature information, I get back the correct response - a 401 Unauthorized and a "WWW-Authenticate: amx" header (where "amx" is the authentication scheme I'm using for testing.  If I include the authorization header in Fiddler then I get a 500 Internal Server Error

My biggest question is how can I debug the Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition?  I have breakpoints set on all the methods (e.g. the Post method in my GetPricesController : ApiController as well as my HMACAuthenticationAttribute which implements the IAuthenticationFilter).  I feel that if I can at least start seeing what's going on when I make the requests with Fiddler, that I may be able to figure out the web app from there.

I'm supposed to be doing a demo on this Web API project tomorrow early afternoon and I've been working for the back 11 hours on finishing this up but I'm completely stalled now and have no idea where to go from here.  Any help/guidance would be so greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

P.S. I was using this article http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/ to implement the API key validation.

Comment: Also if you have 2 project in your solution, you could only one "Set as startup project". This is the one you could debug. The best way to debug this combination (Web App and Web-API) is first running the Web-API in debugger and call it from external tool (Fiddler, Postman, etc). When it works like expected, you could run it "normal" and start web application in debugger.

Comment: We have our asp.net json api and angular JS frontend in separate solutions. This way you can start both of them in debug mode.